# Closing an "open" AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've built an API using AWS ElasticBeanstalk with integrated EC2 + Postgres RDS, and secured the endpoints with OAuth 2.

I received an email from an independent security auditor with a picture that they were able to gain access to production ENV variables. The ENV variables are managed through Elastic Beanstalk's configuration.

Here's a snippet of the picture they shared, in which they clearly have access to the ENVs:

[image]

**I'm curious how they were able to view these sensitive env variables.**

Comment: Port 5432 is PostgreSQL database, yes? You should not normally expose a database to the internet, only to the application server(s) that need access. Fixing that almost certainly won't resolve your environment exposure, however. Did the security auditor not provide you with information about how they retrieved the environment variables? Ask them, if not. Was it via the HTTP endpoint on port 80, or (unlikely) through SSH access on port 22? Perhaps an SSRF attack (example [here](https://notsosecure.com/exploiting-ssrf-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)).

Comment: @jarmod thanks. RE "only to the application server(s) that need access" — so for "source" I should select the security group belonging to the EC2 instance, right?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you genuinely don't need access to the DB from the public internet. See [VPC Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.VPCSec). If possible, test changes on a non-production environment first, of course.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are publishing an API on port 80 via PHP with no firewalling or access control.
2. You are running debugbar on a production site.

Basically, debugbar has very kindly included *all* of your environment variables in your HTML page.

```
<head></head><body style="margin-bottom: 38px;">Welcome to the Spywatch Lex Staging API ver 1.0<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" property="stylesheet" href="//3.95.51.53/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1586742726"><script type="text/javascript" src="//3.95.51.53/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1586742726"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var phpdebugbar = new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar();
phpdebugbar.addTab("messages", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"list-alt","title":"Messages", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MessagesWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addIndicator("time", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"clock-o","tooltip":"Request Duration"}), "right");
phpdebugbar.addTab("timeline", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"tasks","title":"Timeline", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.TimelineWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addIndicator("memory", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"cogs","tooltip":"Memory Usage"}), "right");
phpdebugbar.addTab("exceptions", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"bug","title":"Exceptions", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.ExceptionsWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("views", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"leaf","title":"Views", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.TemplatesWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("route", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"share","title":"Route", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addIndicator("currentroute", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"share","tooltip":"Route"}), "right");
phpdebugbar.addTab("queries", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"database","title":"Queries", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.LaravelSQLQueriesWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("emails", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"inbox","title":"Mails", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MailsWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("auth", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"lock","title":"Auth", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addIndicator("auth.name", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"user","tooltip":"Auth status"}), "right");
phpdebugbar.addTab("gate", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"list-alt","title":"Gate", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MessagesWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("session", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"archive","title":"Session", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.addTab("request", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"tags","title":"Request", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
phpdebugbar.setDataMap({
"messages": ["messages.messages", []],
"messages:badge": ["messages.count", null],
"time": ["time.duration_str", '0ms'],
"timeline": ["time", {}],
"memory": ["memory.peak_usage_str", '0B'],
"exceptions": ["exceptions.exceptions", []],
"exceptions:badge": ["exceptions.count", null],
"views": ["views", []],
"views:badge": ["views.nb_templates", 0],
"route": ["route", {}],
"currentroute": ["route.uri", ],
"queries": ["queries", []],
"queries:badge": ["queries.nb_statements", 0],
"emails": ["swiftmailer_mails.mails", []],
"emails:badge": ["swiftmailer_mails.count", null],
"auth": ["auth.user", {}],
"auth.name": ["auth.name", ],
"gate": ["gate.messages", []],
"gate:badge": ["gate.count", null],
"session": ["session", {}],
"request": ["request", {}]
});
phpdebugbar.restoreState();
phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler = new PhpDebugBar.AjaxHandler(phpdebugbar);
phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler.bindToXHR();
phpdebugbar.setOpenHandler(new PhpDebugBar.OpenHandler({"url":"http:\/\/3.95.51.53\/_debugbar\/open"}));
phpdebugbar.addDataSet({"__meta":{"id":"1d34aa80b5b5d635d1fb5842750a3165","datetime":"2020-10-29 15:01:14","utime":1603983674.769273,"method":"GET","uri":"\/1.0","ip":"86.191.207.60"},"php":{"version":"7.2.19","interface":"apache2handler"},"messages":{"count":0,"messages":[]},"time":{"start":1603983674.682,"end":1603983674.769287,"duration":0.08728718757629395,"duration_str":"87.29ms","measures":[{"label":"Booting","start":1603983674.682,"relative_start":0,"end":1603983674.767149,"relative_end":1603983674.767149,"duration":0.08514904975891113,"duration_str":"85.15ms","params":[],"collector":null},{"label":"Application","start":1603983674.68708,"relative_start":0.005079984664916992,"end":1603983674.769289,"relative_end":1.9073486328125e-6,"duration":0.08220911026000977,"duration_str":"82.21ms","params":[],"collector":null}]},"memory":{"peak_usage":4194304,"peak_usage_str":"4MB"},"exceptions":{"count":0,"exceptions":[]},"views":{"nb_templates":0,"templates":[]},"route":{"uri":"GET 1.0","middleware":"cors","uses":"Closure {#132\n  class: \"App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider\"\n  this: App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider {#106 \u2026}\n  file: \"\/var\/app\/current\/app\/Http\/routes.php\"\n  line: \"22 to 25\"\n}","namespace":"App\\Http\\Controllers","prefix":"\/1.0","where":[],"file":"app\/Http\/routes.php:22-25"},"queries":{"nb_statements":0,"nb_failed_statements":0,"accumulated_duration":0,"accumulated_duration_str":"0\u03bcs","statements":[]},"swiftmailer_mails":{"count":0,"mails":[]},"auth":{"name":"Guest","user":{"guest":true}},"gate":{"count":0,"messages":[]},"session":{"_token":"j8Z5CzG5Laiomm5HyeJM7ZmKCP14llKHn6wyORkW","PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA":"[]","_previous":"array:1 [\n  \"url\" => \"http:\/\/3.95.51.53\"\n]","flash":"array:2 [\n  \"old\" => []\n  \"new\" => []\n]"},"request":{"format":"html","content_type":"text\/html; charset=UTF-8","status_text":"OK","status_code":"200","request_query":"[]","request_request":"[]","request_headers":"array:8 [\n  \"host\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"3.95.51.53\"\n  ]\n  \"user-agent\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:81.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/81.0\"\n  ]\n  \"accept\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,application\/xml;q=0.9,image\/webp,*\/*;q=0.8\"\n  ]\n  \"accept-language\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"en-US,en;q=0.5\"\n  ]\n  \"accept-encoding\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"gzip, deflate\"\n  ]\n  \"connection\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"keep-alive\"\n  ]\n  \"cookie\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjZxK0NmeFJRSjJwbE5JbDdPS0h1VWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUFVoYUxXSnlOanJFSWg2SHNsYWlZK2Z6SlR2aFFtcGEzM21xWUJWckJFTDZFdmVGd2l4S01cL3FRWkFjejNDZzNhbXJTdlR3WWtxWUZidW9vT2puV2lBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0MTRlN2U4YTgxNmJjMWE0YWNlNjMzYjc2YWI3ZmVmOGY3MmVkYWUwZWZhMDJmMmU4ZTg2NTljNGQ4OTBjY2M0In0%3D\"\n  ]\n  \"upgrade-insecure-requests\" => array:1 [\n    0 => \"1\"\n  ]\n]","request_server":"array:99 [\n  \"REDIRECT_APP\" => \"https:\/\/staging.spywatchlex.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_APP_ENV\" => \"staging\"\n  \"REDIRECT_MAIL_USERNAME\" => \"postmaster@mg.spywatchlex.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_MAILGUN_DOMAIN\" => \"postmaster@mg.spywatchlex.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_APP_KEY\" => \"******\"\n  \"REDIRECT_DB_HOST\" => \"aa1czcdcnsnpmyq.cuqlyug9ccbu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_QUEUE_DRIVER\" => \"sync\"\n  \"REDIRECT_MAIL_PORT\" => \"2525\"\n  \"REDIRECT_OAUTH_TTL\" => \"86400\"\n  \"REDIRECT_SESSION_DRIVER\" => \"file\"\n  \"REDIRECT_TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL\" => \"https:\/\/staging.spywatchlex.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_DB_USERNAME\" => \"Growler\"\n  \"REDIRECT_EMAIL_BASE_URL\" => \"https:\/\/staging.spywatchlex.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_DB_CONNECTION\" => \"pgsql\"\n  \"REDIRECT_CACHE_DRIVER\" => \"file\"\n  \"REDIRECT_APP_DEBUG\" => \"true\"\n  \"REDIRECT_MAIL_PASSWORD\" => \"******\"\n  \"REDIRECT_MAILGUN_SECRET\" => \"******\"\n  \"REDIRECT_DB_DATABASE\" => \"spywatch-lex\"\n  \"REDIRECT_DB_PASSWORD\" => \"******\"\n  \"REDIRECT_RDS_PORT\" => \"5432\"\n  \"REDIRECT_RDS_HOSTNAME\" => \"aa1czcdcnsnpmyq.cuqlyug9ccbu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com\"\n  \"REDIRECT_RDS_USERNAME\" => \"Growler\"\n  \"REDIRECT_RDS_DB_NAME\" => \"ebdb\"\n  \"REDIRECT_RDS_PASSWORD\" => \"******\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT\" => \"512M\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME\" => \"60\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS\" => \"Off\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS\" => \"\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN\" => \"On\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION\" => \"Off\"\n  \"REDIRECT_PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT\" => \
```

You get the picture.  It's a small mercy the passwords are somewhat redacted.

Steps to reproduce:

1. load your landing page
2. click "view source"
3. expand the `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` block.

Please do several things.

1. change your passwords.
2. remove this API from the public internet
3. uninstall phpdebug from your production api
4. spend some time familiarizing yourself with how to actually secure PHP and AWS.

Sorry if this comes across as abrasive, but I don't even KNOW php and I found this in five minutes.